# How to install Dart in Google Compute Engine (GCE)?

Tags: dart, google-compute-engine, server

I am trying to learn both Dart and GCE. I already created a server at GCE, but I don't know how to install Dart since I can only use Linux commands on the Debian server.

Comment: This is not a good StackOverflow question (asking for external ressources). I answered anyway. Please use the instructions and ask again if you have a concrete problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly about Dart on AppEngine:

You should be able to find all information here https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/ 
I did it using the instructions from this page and the linked pages at the bottom.
The discussions here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/cloud provide some useful bits too.

Dart on Compute engine:

Here is a blog post that covers it pretty good http://financecoding.github.io/blog/2013/09/30/getting-started-with-dart-on-compute-engine/ but some things have changed since this was written.

There are docker images https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker ready to execute Dart scripts.
Just search for information how to use Docker images with GCE and you should be fine (there should already be a lot available)

Please ask again if you encounter concrete problems.

Dart on AppEngine runs as Managed VM. Managed VMs work differently than real AppEngine VMs that run 'native' supported languages like Java, Python, and Go. Managed VMs are in fact Compute engines but managed by AppEngine. This means they are launched and shut down depending on the load (and depending on some basic configuration settings in `app.yaml` and also depending on payment settings) while Compute Engines instances are basically always on. You have to manage yourself when instances should be added/removed depending on the load. There is Kubernetes which is a handy tool to make this easier but you have to actually manage your instances. Besides from that there is not much difference between Managed VMs and Compute Engine instances. A difference to native AppEngine is that you can add any libraries and also binaries to Managed VMs like to CE.
There are pricing differences but I don't know details about this myself yet

Comment: Thanks Gunter! I had already seen that page before but it only contained the video so I just skipped it. I see it has new links that are very useful.

Comment: They seem to have updated their services, which the promise on the video, but I wasn't ready when I saw it. Since I am just learning I'll use the easiest one which seems to be App Engine.

Comment: Would you recommend Compute Engine over App Engine for any particular reason?

Comment: I extended my answer. I'm rather new to AppEngine/Compute Engine/Managed VMs myself yet but I hope it provides some help anyway.

Comment: If you're writing web apps in Dart, Managed VMs are a better fit as they provide a number of features such as automatic scaling (up and down), load balancing, etc., so you don't have to manage infrastructure and just concentrate on your app. You can certainly install Dart natively in a GCE VM or run it via Docker but it will require more work from you (admin, maintenance, upgrades) which you might not want to spend your time on. GCE is useful when you want go beyond what the AppEngine/Managed VM environment allows, which doesn't sound like you need at this time.